# Linux; Permission Denied error while installing Matlab

Tags: matlab, terminal, ubuntu-20.04

I am installing Matlab for Linux.
As per tutorials, the command in terminal was `sudo ./install`.
But, the error shows

> ./install: 1: exec: /home/ril/Downloads/Matlab-R2020a_linux64/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You should probably contact MathWorks support for installation issues

Comment: Is the executable bit set for the file you downloaded? `chmod a+x /home/ril/Downloads/Matlab-R2020a_linux64/bin/glnxa64/install_unix`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo No it wasn't. I added the line to it but the error now read "Unable to launch MATLABWindow application". Tried troubleshooting on it, found that we need to download libselinux package from AUR. Downloaded that, but the error says "makepkg command not found". Installed using command "sudo apt-get install pacman" but the error persists